# How to install clang 3.9 or higher using apt-get on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, apt, clang

I know that there are similar questions for installation of clang-lower versions. But, I am trying to follow them to install clang-3.9 or 4.0 , but I am unable to do so on my Linux Mint 18.

First, I was only getting options upto clang-3.8 using

```
sudo apt-get install clang
```

followed by pressing tab twice.

Then, I followed this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/823646/how-can-i-install-clang-3-9-on-ubuntu-12-04) and followed whatever is there in the first answer.

Now, I can see clang-3.9 and clang-4.0 when I press tab after typing 
`sudo apt-get install clang`.

Now, when I do

```
sudo apt-get install clang-4.0
```

I get the following error:-

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 clang-4.0 : Depends: libjsoncpp0 (>= 0.6.0~rc2) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version of Mint is based on Ubuntu 16.04, so you should use the sources for that (as documented on the [repository's main page](http://apt.llvm.org/)):

```
deb http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial main
deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial main
# 3.8
deb http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-3.8 main
deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-3.8 main
# 3.9
deb http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-3.9 main
deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-3.9 main
```

You shouldn't need the `ubuntu-toolchain-r/test` PPA.

Comment: Now, I have replaced the lines in the sources.txt file with the ones you mentioned. But, now I am getting another error similar to the previous one, but now it says :- > The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> clang-4.0:i386 : Depends: binutils:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. And please  forgive my unformatted comment, whenever I am pressing <Enter> , the comment is getting posted. Also tell me if  I should edit my question to have a further question like this?

Comment: Looking at the repositories, it appears that `clang-4.0` isn't currently being built for `amd64` for some reason. You should be able to install `clang-3.9`, but you'll have to wait for LLVM to make `amd64` binaries available to install `clang-4.0`.